# Scrapy suddenly stopped working, gives error

Tags: scrapy, pip

Scrapy 1.4.0 stopped working 3 days ago, before that was fine and crawling. I changed nothing to it.

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 6, in 
<module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given
```

Whats happening, I tried to downgrade scrapy to 1.3.0 still getting same error, also I reinstalled it having same error?

My OS is Centos 7, and I have not updated recently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some information about your Operating System (and if there have been some updates recently).

Comment: I updated the question, os is centos 7 and havent updated recently.

Comment: Something may have gone off with your installation. run `pip install scrapy --force --upgrade` and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: @TarunLalwani solved the issue thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in rare case your packages installation can get corrupt. You should make sure to do a clean install of required packages in such instances. Use below command to reinstall scrapy

```
pip install scrapy --force --upgrade
```